# How to call wifi configuration screen?

Tags: android, configuration, android-intent

How do call the wifi configuration screen from my application?

How do i create the intent to call it?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```

Import `Setting` class that belongs to the `android.provider` package.

Comment: grate. can we set activity_result in this . so if user tap and turn on then redirect to app not stay on same screen